# Managed metadata columns show numbers instead of terms in document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column, managed-metadata

In Sharepoint Online, when I open a document library that has managed metadata columns, everything looks fine.

[image]

However, when I preview a document and close the preview, the managed metadata terms are replaced by numbers for the document I just previewed.

[image]

This seems to only happen when a document library is opened fresh from a hyperlink or the document library page is refreshed, and the metadata terms show up again if you alter filtering/grouping in the document library, but I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid this happening at all? It can be very confusing to the average user when it looks like the tags are wrong on a document.

Comment: Is ut happening for every document library or just this one? Have you tried creating another and adding metadata to it?

Comment: This is happening for all document libraries, yes. I've tried it in site collections that I've heavily worked on and site collections that are practically new, and this seems pretty consistent.

Comment: An additional piece of information: I just noticed this only happens for columns that have the "Require that this column contains information" setting turned on to "Yes". Columns that don't require information to be entered are not affected by this.